# try to change his opinion or try changing his opinion

Tags: meaning, differences, gerunds

A powerful opponent made a long speech criticizing John. This speech was so powerful that it threatened John's political career. John decided to **try to change** his rival's opinion of him. To do this, he sent a letter to him asking for a favor.

Instead of using "try to change", can I use this expression "try changing"? Does it sound awkward? Grammatically wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try + gerund:

> "Try + gerund" means to try or to experiment with different methods to
> see if something works.
>
> **For example:** She tried eating the snake soup, but she didn't like it.

Try + infinitive:

> When you "try to do" something, you want to do it, but you do not
> succeed in actually doing it. In the sentence above, an infinitive is
> used because she cannot successfully climb the tree.
>
> **For example:** Try not to wake the baby when you get up tomorrow at 5 AM.

[Source](https://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_or_infinitive_different_list.htm)

Comment: So you mean, "try changing" doesn't work in this case, right?